# Procedure to change the default font in JOptionPane.showInputDialog gives mixed results

Tags: java, fonts

At 70 years of age I have decided to learn Java, a task that I must say has given me sometimes a lot of frustration. For the purpose of displaying a list  of items for selection, I decided to make use of the `showInputDialog` option of the `JOptionFrame` class, which I found to work with a perfect alignment whenever the fault font is changed to monospaced by making a call to the UIManager like this: `UIManager.put("List.font", new Font( "monospaced",Font.PLAIN,14));`

The problem is that this ceases to work with the font returning to whatever its default value is whenever I insert a list in what I suppose to be called the parent frame. I can insert other objects without any problem, but not a list. My question is: what am I doing wrong? Relevant code bellow.

```
UIManager.put("List.font", new Font( "monospaced",Font.PLAIN,14));

String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
        "World Exchanges",
        "Please select one", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, 
        choices, choices[0]); // Initial choice
```

Comment: *At 70 years of age I have decided to learn Java* - That, sir, is **awesome**.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: @user1803551 is right.  It is going to be hard to figure out what is going on without a MCVE that other people can compile, run and debug.

Comment: If you managed to remove code until it works then you just need to add line by line your old code until the problem resumes, then you will find the line(s) that cause the problem. This will allow you to crate a proper [mcve]. Post that and someone will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that this is a consequence of inconsistent look-and-feel caching behavior.  The javadocs for `UIManager` say this:

> The set of defaults a particular look and feel supports is defined and documented by that look and feel. In addition, each look and feel, or ComponentUI provided by a look and feel, may access the defaults at different times in their life cycle. Some look and feels may aggressively look up defaults, so that changing a default may not have an effect after installing the look and feel. Other look and feels may lazily access defaults so that a change to the defaults may effect an existing look and feel. Finally, other look and feels might not configure themselves from the defaults table in any way. None-the-less it is usually the case that a look and feel expects certain defaults, so that in general a ComponentUI provided by one look and feel will not work with another look and feel.

My recommendation (based on this) would be to make this call:

```
UIManager.put("List.font", new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN,14));
```

*after* selecting the look-and-feel (if you do that), and *before* instantiating any Swing components.

Comment: This is a safe guess, but as you said, just a guess. We don't know when the Swing thread starts or when the problem starts ("*whenever I insert a list in what I suppose to be called the parent frame*" doesn't make sense for Swing). I would venture my own guess that they need to call `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(...)` after the problem is supposed to start.

Comment: @1803551 Thanks for you advise, which I have followed by reducing the code to no more than half a dozen lines. The problem is that by doing that the issue went away.

Comment: @PeterCarva Please use the full name after @ to ping a user, and reply where the relevant discussion is (under the question in this case). This is not a forum where everything is appended at the bottom.

Comment: @Stephen You are probably right in the sense that it has to do with what I call the internal aspects about which I know nothing. I have been relying on the default look and feel, which I presume to be java. While  playing around I noticed that if a change the value of the  default.font to what I want it only affects a single line, the line  that has been selected. That is,

Comment: @PeterCarva - When you tried my suggestion, did it have the desired effect?

Comment: @Stefen C and user1803551 you were right . It started working as intended  after I moved  the call to the UIManager to the constructor placing it  just before calling the initComponents()  method.Sorry guys but I could not answer you back yesterday as I spent most of the day in hospital for the purpose of doing a biopsy. . Thank you very much for your advice.